# How do i downgrade to Init-System-helper V1.13

Tags: linux, terminal, ppa

How do i downgrade to Init-system-helper V1.13?

I tried to $wget it from here, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/powerpc/init-system-helpers/1.18

```
 wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/init-system-helpers/1.13
```

But it won't let me dpkg it, it will simply state that it does not exist.

```
 E: Unable to locate package init-system-helpers_1.13_all.deb
 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'init-system-helpers_1.13_all.deb'
 root@1:~#
```

I also can't PPA https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/powerpc/init-system-helpers/1.18 this for some reason. I might be doing it wrong.

```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/init-system-helpers/1.13
```

The reason i want to downgrade is because RabbitMQ is throwing the following error when trying to install their server.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: rabbitmq-server : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~) but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~)
```

means `rabbitmq-server` needs `init-system-helper` 1.13 *or later*, so the default version in any supported release of Ubuntu should satisfy the dependency. Just run

```
sudo apt-get install init-system-helpers
```

However you’re still using Ubuntu 12.04 which doesn’t have `init-system-helpers`. You need to upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: Well, running  sudo apt-get install init-system-helpers, gives the following,              
Package init-system-helpers is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'init-system-helpers' has no installation candidate

Comment: That’s probably because you’re using an unsupported version of Ubuntu, so you need to update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to use `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu`.

Comment: I gedit into my               `/etc/apt/sources.list   `              and it is right there, `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner`, see https://i.gyazo.com/1c0d1f079293f206f6c3f25596d0a4e5.png Should i update it to `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: Isn't there a PPA which i would be able to add which simulates the process, as a workaround?

Comment: 12.04 is too old, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Okay. I now got it fixed, but the next error popped up rather quickly. `* Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                                                                                                                                                                                    * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
`

Comment: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` https://i.gyazo.com/1af694eda593468fcacf37ef3f98c6a2.png

Comment: You should ask a new question, and include the contents of the log files mentioned in the RabbitMQ error message.